# Getting the Row for Section indexPath in a tableView

Tags: ios, indexing, row, tableview

Recently I put implemented an indexing feature for the user names in my app. I have been trying to access the rows in each section and add them to my recipients array when the user taps the index path. I have tried passing many different values in my objectAtIndex: method but none seem to be working. I am able to log the correct index row and section in indexPathForRow:inSection: method but the return value is an indexPath and not an integer. So something with my objectForIndex: method is obviously not right. Any help or references would be super. cheers!

This line:

`PFUser *user = [self.friends objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];`

Returns only the first username in each section, no matter what name I tap in the section. So I need to access the Row in addition, not just the section.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

int section = indexPath.section;
int row = indexPath.row;
NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
NSLog(@"newIndexPath: %@", newIndexPath);

PFUser *user = [self.friends objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    [self.recipients addObject:user.objectId];
NSLog(@"added:%@",user);
}
else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    [self.recipients removeObject:user.objectId];
    NSLog(@"removed:%@",user);
}

[self.currentUser saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
}
```

Comment: if you want to get selected row's number and section then you just need to write `indexPath.row` and `indexPath.section` ... no need to do any things else :) and also only `indexPath` dose not return integer value.. :)

Comment: what is your data source.....

Comment: @iPatel but how would I pass both of those values in for `PFUser *user = [self.friends objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];`?

Comment: PFUser *user = [self.friends objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];// What is your model of data source.... is it array of object or array of array of objects

Comment: What is PFUser *user  and also your question bit more create confusion please can you elaborate it ??

Comment: @Spynet I have the names stored in section arrays in a collation.

Comment: PFUser is an object being stored in the backend on Parse. It has keys for username, date, relation, etc.

Comment: u have only one section ?.... can u add code for number of section method???

Comment: please post the section code ......

Comment: quite new to this and 100% self taught. so I'm not entirely sure I'm doing everything correctly. But since I am able to log the correct section and row.. I feel like I can't be too far off. I hope.

Comment: NSIndexpath is the class please read the documentaion https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40152/discussion-between-spynet-and-jared-gross)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi this is enough try and let me know if you face any issues...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

NSArray * nameArray = [self.sectionsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

PFUser *user = (PFUser*)[nameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

// PFUser *user = (PFUser*)[self.friends objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) 
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    [self.recipients addObject:user.objectId];
NSLog(@"added:%@",user);
}
else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    [self.recipients removeObject:user.objectId];
    NSLog(@"removed:%@",user);
}
// this is enough
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just like the code Spynet suggested only a little bit different:

```
NSArray *array = [self.sectionsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    PFUser *user = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Using that code I was able to get the proper indexPath for row in each section. Also, in order to get the cells accessory checkmarks to work correctly I had to create a newIndexPath using the section and row values for each index. My final code is here:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    int row = indexPath.row;
    int section = indexPath.section;

    NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
    NSLog(@"newIndexPath: %@", newIndexPath);

    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath animated:NO];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath];

    NSLog(@"sectionsArray:%@",self.sectionsArray);

    NSArray *array = [self.sectionsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    PFUser *user = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"array:%@",array);
    NSLog(@"user:%@",user);

    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [self.recipients addObject:user];
        NSLog(@"recipients:%@",self.recipients);
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [self.recipients removeObject:user];
        NSLog(@"recipients:%@",self.recipients);
    }

    [self.currentUser saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
}
```